# specify filename and header for datatable pdf output r shiny

Tags: r, pdf, datatable, shiny

I have a shiny app like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

tabledata <- data.table(a=1:4, b= 5:8)
ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("currenttable")
)
server <-  function(input,output, session){
  output$currenttable <- renderDataTable({tabledata},rownames = FALSE, extensions = 'Buttons', 
                                         options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',    buttons = c('copy', 'pdf'), 
                                                        filename = "CurrentTable", header= "My Header", pageLength = nrow(tabledata))
                                         )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The pdf button works, but only saves the file as "pdf.pdf"  not "CurrentTable" and header is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You'll need to [bind the options to the `pdf` button](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/213#issuecomment-205522155). You can include `filename` and `header` options in this way.
2. From the [DataTable `pdf` reference](https://datatables.net/reference/button/pdf), `header` indicates whether the table header (i.e. column names) should be included in the exported table or not -- this can only be `TRUE` or `FALSE`, not a string. If you're looking for a title above the table, you could use the `title` option.

Here's your example:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(DT)

tabledata <- data.table(a=1:4, b= 5:8)
ui <- fluidPage(
        DT::dataTableOutput("currenttable")
)
server <-  function(input,output, session){
        output$currenttable <- renderDT({tabledata},
                                        rownames = FALSE, 
                                        extensions = 'Buttons', 
                                        options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                                       pageLength = nrow(tabledata),
                                                       buttons = list(
                                                               list(extend = 'copy'),
                                                               list(extend = 'pdf',
                                                                    filename = 'CurrentTable',
                                                                    title = "My Title",
                                                                    header = FALSE)
                                                       )
                                                       )
                                        )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```